# Query limit to 5 and add load more to load another 5 in PFQueryTableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquerytableviewcontrolle

How do I query limit 5 and once user scroll down , it will load another 5

Here's the code

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
        var query = PFQuery(className: "product")
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")


        return query
    }
```

Do I need to set a limit?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, there is that PFQuery limitation method

```
 query.limit = 5
```

Comment: how do i load another 5 items after user scrolled?

Comment: you can get the scroll position and increase the limit count

Comment: How do i get the scroll position?